# Open second instance of notepad++ not in administrator

Tags: notepad++

How can I open a second instance of notepad++ not in administrator's mode when the first instance is in administrator's mode?

If the first instance is not in administrator's mode I get an option to open a new instance in administrator's mode if I need to save a file that needs it, but if the first instance is in administrator's mode how can I open a second instance of notepad++ not in administrator mode?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the behavior you describe by going to `Settings -> Preferences -> Multi-Instance` and choosing `Always in multi-instance mode`. Then, opening N++ as administrator, launching it again opened a new instance as a regular user.

The other options won't work for me.

[image]